# How to tell Meteor to ignore `gulpfile.js`

Tags: meteor, gulp

In my meteor project I want to use [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) for tasks meteor doesn't support.
Anyway, the problem is that gulp uses a file called `gulpfile.js` which is loaded by meteor too and gives errors. So my question is, is there a way to tell meteor to ignore some files ?

UPDATE: One solution I can think of is to put `gulpfile.js` in the folder `packages` or `public` and run gulp as follows

```
$> gulp --gulpfile packages/gulpfile.js
```

UPDATE: Just noticed that meteor also seems to load node_modules files :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, in the current release there's no way to tell Meteor to leave certain files alone, so you cannot have `gulpfile.js` in your main app folder.

You can, however, leave it in an ignored subfolder. Meteor ignores files and directories that ends with tilde `~`, the `/tests` directory and all private files (those beginning with a dot `.`). So you can create a folder named for example `gulp~` and use it for your gulp-related stuff.

---

The same holds for `node_modules` folder, you cannot have it in your application, and you shouldn't. If you want to use a node package in your Meteor application, you can do this with `npm` package.

- Add it to your project with `mrt add npm` command.
- Then create `packages.json` file with a list of all required packages, for example:

  ```
  {
    "something":       "1.5.0",
    "something-else":  "0.9.11"
  }
  ```
- Afterwards, include your package with `Meteor.require`:

  var something = Meteor.require('something');

If you want to use a node package in your gulp tasks, install it inside the ignored directory.

Comment: thnx, I tried to move everything into a directory called `gulp~`, but gives me the same result (errors). It seems that meteor doesn't ignore this directory. Could it be that the recent version of meteor changed this behaviour ?

Comment: It's wasn't documented, so it's possible that it's changed. Try `.gulp`. If the problem persists, the reason must be somewhere else.